# Setting multiple button texts to fields in a database with one identifying field

Tags: c#, sql, database, loops, ms-access

I've been trying to fix this all day and finally figured I can't engineer my way out of this problem :)

So, from memory looping through records in a database normally works like this... (I think)

```
while(reader.Read())
{
    btn.Text = reader["Field Name"].ToString();
    btn2.Text = reader["Field Name"].ToString();
}
```

I assumed this would write the first field text to the first button and then the next field name to the next button. Instead it writes the last field contents to all the buttons.

I am trying to write 4 field contents from 4 records to 4 buttons, sequentially, so button1 = record(row)1 field, button2 = record2 field etc...

This is the original code:

```
private void Homework_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM HWTasks WHERE TwyID = '" + Login.TwyIDRetrieve + "'";
        int OccuranceNo = 0;
        OccuranceNo = (Int32)command.ExecuteScalar();
        command.Dispose();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM HWTasks WHERE TwyID = '" + Login.TwyIDRetrieve + "'";
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (OccuranceNo == 1)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                HwTskBtn1.Text = reader["TaskName"].ToString();
            }
        }
        else if (OccuranceNo == 2)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                HwTskBtn1.Text = reader["TaskName"].ToString();
                HwTskBtn2.Text = reader["TaskName"].ToString();
            }
        }
        else if (OccuranceNo == 3)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                HwTskBtn1.Text = reader["TaskName"].ToString();
                HwTskBtn2.Text = reader["TaskName"].ToString();
                HwTskBtn3.Text = reader["TaskName"].ToString();
            }
        }
        else if (OccuranceNo == 4)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                HwTskBtn1.Text = reader["TaskName"].ToString();
                HwTskBtn2.Text = reader["TaskName"].ToString();
                HwTskBtn3.Text = reader["TaskName"].ToString();
                HwTskBtn4.Text = reader["TaskName"].ToString();
            }
        }
```

But tried this first:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (OccuranceNo == 1)
    {
        HwTskBtn1.Text = reader["TaskName"].ToString();
    }
    else if (OccuranceNo == 2)
    {
        HwTskBtn1.Text = reader["TaskName"].ToString();
        HwTskBtn2.Text = reader["TaskName"].ToString();
    }
    else if (OccuranceNo == 3)
    {
        HwTskBtn1.Text = reader["TaskName"].ToString();
        HwTskBtn2.Text = reader["TaskName"].ToString();
        HwTskBtn3.Text = reader["TaskName"].ToString();
    }
    else if (OccuranceNo == 4)
    {
        HwTskBtn1.Text = reader["TaskName"].ToString();
        HwTskBtn2.Text = reader["TaskName"].ToString();
        HwTskBtn3.Text = reader["TaskName"].ToString();
        HwTskBtn4.Text = reader["TaskName"].ToString();
    }
    else if (OccuranceNo > 4)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: There are more than 4 homework tasks set for your account, contact your teacher/administrator to resolve/nTasks set out of expected range!", "Oops!");
    }
}
```

Thank you to anyone who can help me!
Liam

Comment: The row number "advances" when you call `Read()` on the `reader`, not when you access each field. we could go ahead and give you an answer with the exact code you need, but that would be of no help to you. Try to reason how it works and try some more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't want to give an exact answer (which would be really easy), but more trying to make you understand how everything works. You say:

> I assumed this would write the first field text to the first button and then the next field name to the next button.

That's wrong.

When you have your `OleDbDataReader` variable, `Read()` assigns the fields from the current row and advances the internal cursor to the next row (if there's any). It also returns `true` if there was actually any row to read, or `false` if it was at the end.

So let's try to write this loop:

```
while(reader.Read())
{
    btn.Text = reader["Field Name"].ToString();
    btn2.Text = reader["Field Name"].ToString();
}
```

In a more sensible manner, and with comments:

```
bool thereAreMoreRows = reader.Read(); // We read the first row, if it exists
                                       // thereAreMoreRows contains true
                                       // if we read a row, or false if
                                       // we didn't

while(thereAreMoreRows)  // Repeat what is inside the { } while the 
                         // variable thereAreMoreRows is true
                         // Don't enter if it was false
{
   btn.Text = reader["Field Name"].ToString(); // Assign the current row's "Field Name"
                                               // converted to a string to the button "btn" text property

   btn2.Text = reader["Field Name"].ToString(); // Assign the current row's "Field Name" 
                                                // converted to a string to the button "btn2" text property. 
                                                // Note that this is the same we assigned to btn!

   thereAreMoreRows = reader.Read(); // Advance to the next row, and read it
                                     // or set thereAreMoreRows to false if
                                     // there were no more rows

} // Repeat until thereAreMoreRows is false
```

So if you follow the logic, both buttons will contain the same text, and that of the last row's "Field Name", which is exactly what is happening to you.

> Instead it writes the last field contents to all the buttons.

Try to follow along what the code is doing, it should be easy to reason out what is happening in yours, and how you could solve it.

I don't want to give a solution, but just tell you what's wrong and why.

Write your code very verbose so you understand it line by line... once you understand it, it's easy to refactor and optimize it if you understand the "global picture". Your final loop code could be written in just 3 lines, but there's no point on giving you those three lines if you can't get to understand what they are doing.

---

**Update** since, with your answer, it seems the aim of my answer worked, and you are now on the right track, let's see how you could make your loop better and perform as you expected in your initial code.

You can disregard the whole `OccuranceNo`, it's just the count of the tasks. Since you have a non-dynamic UI, the maximum number of tasks to be shown (on buttons) is 4, but you could have less.

So let's put those buttons in an array that we can reference by index:

```
var myButtons = new Button[] { HwTaskBtn1, HwTaskBtn2, HwTaskBtn3, HwTaskBtn4 };
var index = 0;
// either we're up to the 4th index, or there are no more tasks
while(index < 4 && reader.Read())
   myButtons[index++].Text = reader["TaskName"].ToString();
```

It should now be easy to figure out what that code does, while still being clearly readable (note that since the `while` block is just one line, you can remove the brackets `{}`)

The problems in your answer (which this one solves) are:

1. You are assuming there will only be 4 records in the database. If there are more than 4, your code will throw an exception (since it'll try to write to `taskName[4]`, which is out of range).
2. If there are less than 4 rows, your buttons will still be assigned a text (I'm not changing the text of the non-updated buttons either, so this may work for you).

Otherwise, your answer is one way to do it, you are definitely right on track.

There are details that should be specified (what to do with the other buttons when there are no tasks for them, should we show an error when there are more than 4 tasks, should we hide the unassigned buttons, etc.), but that's what specifications are for :-)

Comment: Ah okay, I have been taking the wrong approach, I'm intermediately new to this really and still learning the ways in which to perform tasks! I was thinking throughout that there must of been a way in which to create a loop in a few lines although I decided to work with what I knew at the time! Thanks for a point in the right direction.

Comment: Hope you get it. Once you find the right answer, you'll see how easy it was all this time :-) Do not be worried of writing very long "unrolled" loops if that makes you understand the code better (at least if it's not production code, it's just practice). Once you understand what each line is doing, it's generally quite easy to convert an "unrolled loop" into a tight loop with very little lines of code.

Comment: Your answer really did get me to think about it differently and put me on the right track so I can thank you enough for that, will likely stick with me now! 
Ah okay, so you can actually create an array of buttons! The rest all makes sense and is very concise.
Yep, the system shouldn't allow the manual entry of more than 4 tasks per user anyway, however I might change this and would have to add a condition that either displays an error when the index is more than 4 or increase the size of the array and amount of buttons!
Thank you so much, I've learnt a lot, if only you could be my teacher ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your patience and guidance especially for my first experience on the forum! Liam @Jcl

Answer (score 0):

Created a solution by using an Array, this let me create a loop that was atomic and tiny in comparison to my embarrassment above :) @Jcl I'm sure this isn't exactly what you had mind for a solution and I'm sure you could produce a much much better way, but if this works it is technically considered an answer right? ;)

Array:

```
//count value to step through array
int count = 0;
//array to store row data
string[] taskName = new string[4];
```

Loop then assignment:

```
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //Assigns array point from count variable, reads data from row into array point
                taskName[count] = reader["TaskName"].ToString();
                //counts up the point in the array
                count++;
            }
            HwTskBtn1.Text = taskName[0];
            HwTskBtn2.Text = taskName[1];
            HwTskBtn3.Text = taskName[2];
            HwTskBtn4.Text = taskName[3];
```

Comment: Yep, if it works for you, then it's fine. The problem is that this code is not doing -exactly- what you posted, it's not taking `OccuranceNo` into account... but now that you are on the right track and seems you have understood the code, let me add an update to my answer :-)